# Scala reflection on function parameter names

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class which takes a function

```
 case class FunctionParser1Arg[T, U](func:(T => U))

 def testFunc(name1:String):String = name1
 val res = FunctionParser1Arg(testFunc)
```

I would like to know the type signature information on the function from inside the case class.  I want to know both the parameter name and type.  I have had success in finding the type using the runtime mirror objects, but not the name.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It would have been helpful if you described what you got, as the "path" from there to what you want might have been shorter in the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, let's say you got the symbol for the instance `func` points to:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}

val im = m reflect res.func // Instance Mirror
```

You can get the `apply` method from its type members:

```
val apply = newTermName("apply")
val applySymbol = im.symbol.typeSignature member apply
```

And since we know it's a method, make it a method symbol:

```
val applyMethod = applySymbol.asMethod
```

It's parameters can be found through `paramss`, and we know there's only one parameter on one parameter list, so we can get the first parameter of the first parameter list:

```
val param = applyMethod.paramss(0)(0)
```

Then what you are asking for is:

```
val name = param.name.decoded // if you want "+" instead of "$plus", for example
val type = param.typeSignature
```

It's possible that you think that's the wrong answer because you got `x$1` instead of `name1`, but what is passed to the constructor *is not the named function* `testFunc`, but, instead, an *anonymous function* representing that method created through a process called *eta expansion*. You can't find out the parameter name of the method because you can't *pass* the method.

If that's what you need, I suggest you use a macro instead. With a macro, you'll be able to see exactly what is being passed at compile time and get the name from it.